# C# application pretending its from another country

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service where i do different things according to where ones IP is from. I have a simple test application where i open a WebClient and makes it call the web service. I would like to be able to change the IP on the test application so that it "seems" that it comes from different countries (this will help me test goals in google analytics too) - is this possible - to change/simulate that my application is located in another country (France, Germany, Belgium, England, US, etc...)

Comment: Interesting question, but don't try to get this application through Homeland Security in the United States!  You (or at least the application) will probably end up on a secret flight to Uzbekistan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers more accurately provide a solution, but you could always fake it. Utilise your own small private network and provide a facade to handle IP locationing for DEBUG vs. PRODUCTION mode. All of this of course wouldn't trick Google ;-) but it would help solidify your application.

Sorry for possibly being redundant.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a Proxy or an VPN Tunnel, but you'll need an End-Point in the country you want. But, there are also plenty of lists around the web for this.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to "bounce" through **a proxy ser ver in each of the countries** you wish to test for.  I've had good luck in the past with sites such as [**proxy2free**](http://www.proxy4free.com/page2.html) or [**publicproxyservers**](http://www.publicproxyservers.com/proxy/list_country1.html) in the past.

Other solutions would involve running a client from a host in one of these countries, **by way of a VPN / RDP / RAdmin-type session**, but that implies owning assets or knowing people in these countries who would trust you with using their hosts in this fashion.

Another solution involves **a bit of a program change in your application**.  By detection of a particular trigger (could be one of several different IPs but from the same country where you reside, could be some added parameter on the url such as &ctrytest=Spain etc.)  your application would substitute the IP with one of several foreign IP (from the desired countries) *at the level of the country detection logic* in your code, but otherwise using the real IP  from your client request to actually serve the application.

Answer (score 0):

You probably realize it based on the previous answers, but just to be sure: IP addresses are not a certain indicator of the country a user is in. For example, I once worked in the US for a UK-based company, and we used IP addresses allocated to a UK-based ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Ultrasurf may help: http://ultrasurf.en.softonic.com/

I don't think you can specify though, exactly where in the world your request is sent from.